# Finding Facebook mutual friends using GRAPH

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to using Facebook API, I've managed to get all the data I need but seems like getting number of mutual friends is not possible anymore.
I've tried using this URL I found online to get them:

https://graph.facebook.com/"friend1-facebook-id"/mutualfriends?user="friend2-facebook-id"&access_token="your-access-token"

But I'm getting this out of it:

```
{
 "error": {
 "message": "(#12) mutual friends API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 12,
  "fbtrace_id": "ChxQy9XWX8K"
   }
}
```

Is there a way to fix it and get the number? Or is there another straight forward way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/mutual_friends/

The call needs to be

```
GET /v2.6/{user-context-id}/mutual_friends
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the Context ID, this is also possible:

```
/[id-of-friend]?fields=context{mutual_friends}
```

You get a list of mutual friends (who authorized your App too) and a summary field with the number of mutual friends. Just use your own User Access Token.